# Parse Error In SQL PHP statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The Following Statement gives error when executed :

```
$stmt=$db->prepare ("INSERT INTO cabs (NAME,IDNO,HOSTEL,MODE,DATE,TIME,TFNO,CONTACT)
VALUES
(:name,:idno,:hostel,:mode,:date,:time,:tfno,:contact)");

$stmt->bindParam (':name',$_POST[name]);
```

Error Statement :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\overflow\rew1.php on line 27
```

Comment: try putting some quotes around ':name'

Comment: What sort of database is it that you are writing into?

Comment: You need to quote the string `:name` when binding it: `$stmt->bindParam (':name',$_POST[name]);` (and all the others)

Comment: MySQL, MSSQL, PostGreSQL? There are lots of SQL databases!

Comment: @PRP He means, is it MySql, Sql Server, etc.  SQL is a generic language.

Comment: PLS look at new error after putting the quotess..

Comment: Looks like prepare failed. Use `errorInfo` http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: ^ pls explain how....i am using wamp

Comment: `print_r( $stmt->errorInfo() );`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\overflow\rew1.php on line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `'`

```
$stmt=$db->prepare ("INSERT INTO cabs (NAME,IDNO,HOSTEL,MODE,DATE,TIME,TFNO,CONTACT)
VALUES
(:name,:idno,:hostel,:mode,:date,:time,:tfno,:contact)");

$stmt->bindParam (':name',$_POST[name], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Check example at http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Also to anything else that isn't a number?

Comment: I'd say basically yes; however you can specify types by `PDO::PARAM_INT`, `PDO::PARAM_STR` and so on. See update above ...

Comment: yya..is it related to installing PDO....?? because i have not done anything specific to install it

Comment: @Ben: PRP updated the error message above; so now my answer doesn't fit any longer ....

Comment: @PRP: see comment of Ben: `$stmt` is not an object.

Comment: @Ben so what does that mean...?

Comment: @PRP `If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE`. [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Seriously, PHP docs are your best friends, try to debug it yourself from here.

Comment: actually i was mixing up PDO and msqli tht was the problem